# Incorrect number of dimentions?

Tags: r

[This is a sample of the sndata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5j0v.png) I have this code every time I try to run it, it gives me an incorrect number of dimensions.

```
tab<-table(sndata$Visitors)
tab 
y<- data.frame(tab)
y
x<-gvisMotionChart(sndata$Visitors, "Visitors", "Datehour")
plot (x)
```

A sample of the date is this:

```
Focus        Country     Region    City  PrevPage   Pagepath  Pagetitle  Datehour
Admissions    China     Beijing   Beijing  (entrance)  www.bra.ed Inters  20122110
Admissions    China     Beijing Beijing   lts.brandeis.edu  www.b. Undergraduate
```

Cannot get past the fifth line

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample of sndata or sndata$Visitors  ?

Comment: What do the first 4 lines have to do with it?

Comment: Yes, sndata contains information about website entrance, page visits, datehour, and exits. It is a university website which is visited by people all over the world. And I have to analyze it by created charts, such as motion, network and etc.

Comment: Rich Scriven I have do create a motion chart, the first four lines are running successfully, but when it comes to the last line, it is error, because of incorrect dimensions, so maybe the way I'm writing the code is wrong.

Comment: I am unable to correctly post a sample of the data by just copy and paste.

Comment: @dww Uploaded a picture of sample data

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `ab<-table(sndata$Visitors, sndata$Datehour)`?

Comment: @42 it did not work this way as well. I feel like the problem is with the strings but I am not even sure what to replace it with.

Comment: *"unable to correctly post a sample"* ... `dput(head(sndata))`? If it's too wide, perhaps `dput(head(sndata[,1:10]))`?

Comment: @r2evans I have posted it above in the question already.

Comment: No. You posted an image hoping that people volunteering their time to assist you are okay with transcribing data from an image. Though it is necessary some times, for most things related to `[r]` it is easy enough to post representative data as *text* that we can copy and paste into our console. The only legitimate times I can think of when posting the data directly in the question will not work are based on (a) non-atomic structures, therefore requiring code to construct it; or (b) too large, perhaps requiring an external link to *data* (not an image). (Your problem is neither.)

Comment: @r2evans This is my first time doing programming and it is for my big data course. I had no idea you were going to work with it in your console, therefore I thought a picture would suffice. I will type it up right now, thanks for your advice & clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your syntax for `gvisMotionChart()`

```
gvisMotionChart(sndata, idvar="Visitors", timevar="Datehour")
```

Where,

- `sndata` is a dataframe.
- `idvar` is the column to be analysed.
- `timevar` is the column with time dimension. It can be either `numeric` or `date` or `character` class.

Check `?gvisMotionChart` for more details.

Comment: Thanks Karthik for your reply, I took your advice and put it in and it's giving me this message. Error in gvisCheckMotionChartData(data, my.options) : 
  The data must have rows with unique combinations of idvar and timevar.
Your data has 189157 rows, but idvar and timevar only define 1924 unique rows.

Comment: It is quite explicit in the error. You need to reduce the rows by transforming it to some metric like `mean`, `sum`, count `n()`, etc. In your case you can try functions from `dplyr` package. `library(dplyr)`, `sndata <- sndata %>% group_by(Visitors, Datehour) %>% summarise_all(mean)`. Then try passing it to gvisMotionChart. You can share some data with us using `dput(head(sndata))` to provide you the complete solution.

Comment: can you elaborate on how I can share data using dput. pretty new to all this.

Comment: @ShahzodaNasimi if `sndata` is the dataframe in your R environment, then just run `dput(head(sndata))` and copy paste the output in your question here. Check this post on [reproducible-example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: 1           2         3        4       5       6      7      8     10     11     12

Comment: 171113   2382    304     73     13      4      3      3      1      1      1

Comment: The first numbers correspond with the second numbers respectively. creating a table.

Comment: @ShahzodaNasimi No. This is unacceptable. Read the instructions in the link I shared in my previous comment.

Comment: www.brandeis.edu/wsrc/arts/"), class = "factor"), Pageviews = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Newvisits = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), Entrances = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Avgtimeonpage = c(24, 
    0, 5, 6, 8, 12), Exits = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame", vars = list(Visitors, Datehour, Pagepath, 
    Pageviews, Newvisits, Entrances, Avgtimeonpage, Exits), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("Visitors", 
"Datehour", "Pagepath", "Pageviews", "Newvisits", "Entrances", 
"Avgtimeonpage", "Exits")))

Comment: This is whats coming up when I run dput(head(sndata)). The numbers I gave previosly were from dput(head(sndata$Visitors)). There is just so much.

Comment: @ShahzodaNasimi The output in your previous comment is the right format. But the beginning is truncated.

Comment: "www.brandeis.edu/audience/parents.html", "www.brandeis.edu/bgi/people/index.html", 
    "www.brandeis.edu/cgi-bin/soupermail.pl", "www.brandeis.edu/communications/", 
    "www.brandeis.edu/community-engaged/", "www.brandeis.edu/das/", 
    "www.brandeis.edu/departments/afroamerstudies/", "www.brandeis.edu/departments/anthro/", 
    "www.brandeis.edu/departments/anthro/faculty/index.html"  - This is the beginning of the output R is producing. I don't know what to do with this motion chart anymore, it's giving me a hard time. Thanks for your help much.